# ModelMapper throws an error while it's mapping from List to another List

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I map two classes which properties have ArrayLists and ModelMappers works well. I have ModelMapper 3.1.0 version and SpringBoot version 2.7.4. in my project. Here's the snippet of two models: VetClinic and VetCLinicDto:

```
public class VetClinic{
    private ArrayList<Doctor> doctors;
    ...
}
```

```
public class VetClinic{
    private ArrayList<DoctorDto> doctorDtos;
    ...
}
```

And for help ModelMapper with mapping specific fields like Collections I wrote the code:

```
@Override
protected void mapSpecificFieldsToModelFromDto(VetClinicDto source, VetClinic destination) {
    if (source.getDoctors() != null)
        destination.setDoctors(source.getDoctors()
                .stream().map(doctorDto -> mapper.map(doctorDto, Doctor.class))
                .toList());
        ...
}
```

This code snippet works correctly, but where I try to change ArrayList to List like this:

```
public class VetClinic{
    private List<Doctor> doctors;
    ...
}
```

```
public class VetClinic{
    private List<DoctorDto> doctorDtos;
    ...
}
```

The issue occurs when ModelMapper tries to map VetClinicDto to VetClinic but throws an error:

```
1) Failed to instantiate instance of destination java.util.List. Ensure that java.util.List has a non-private no-argument constructor.
```

I've tried to initialize List to ArrayList right away. Like this:

```
public class VetClinic{
    private List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

```
public class VetClinic{
    private List<DoctorDto> doctorDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't work. I can't understand why does ModelMapper cannot map one List to another List.

Answer (score 0):

The details that are missing to answer this question fully is in the "mapper.map(doctorDto, Doctor.class)"

But I would take a look at this link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-list-to-another

It will give you some ideas on how to write your mapper to handle this. I would also suggest you look into using the mapstruct framework to do this mapping for you where it can easily handle mapping lists to lists and also if the objects have the same attributes, there is very little configuration needed.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface DoctorMapper {
List<DoctorDto> map(List<Doctor> doctors);

DoctorDto map(Doctor doctor);
}
```